# jQuery Getting Wrong Value from Checkbox Group?

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

Given the following code, jQuery seems to only alert "1" as the value even after the user has selected radiobutton 2. What am I missing here? Shouldn't the trailing jQuery alert "2" when the second radiobutton is selected?

```
<p>
  Coal  <input type="radio" name="example" value="1" checked /> 
  Candy <input type="radio" name="example" value="2" />
</p>
```

I'm using this code in firebug to test:

```
r = $(":radio[name='example']").val();
alert(r);
```

Comment: Incidentally you're mixing HTML and XHTML syntax there so it's valid for neither. Go for `checked="checked" />` or `checked>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$(":radio[name='example']")` gives you all radios with name=example `.val()` then takes the value of the first of those.  you want `$(":radio[name='example']:checked").val()`